# Search XML files stored in a MS SQL database

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have over 500,000 XML files stored in a MS SQL data base such as the one below (which has been edited to save space in the question).

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <PROJECTS xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <row>
    <APPLICATION_ID>7000518</APPLICATION_ID>
    <ACTIVITY>C06</ACTIVITY>
    <ADMINISTERING_IC>RR</ADMINISTERING_IC>
    <APPLICATION_TYPE>1</APPLICATION_TYPE>
    <BUDGET_START>09/01/2009</BUDGET_START>
    <BUDGET_END>09/30/2013</BUDGET_END>
    <FULL_PROJECT_NUM>1C06RR020539-01A1</FULL_PROJECT_NUM>
    <FY>2009</FY>
    <ORG_STATE>CA</ORG_STATE>
    <ORG_ZIPCODE>900952000</ORG_ZIPCODE>
    <PIS>
    <PI>
    <PI_NAME>JONES,MARY</PI_NAME>
    <PI_ID>9876543</PI_ID>
    </PI>
    <PI>
    <PI_NAME>DOE, JOHN</PI_NAME>
    <PI_ID>1234567</PI_ID>
    </PI>
    </PIS>
    <PROJECT_TERMSX>
    <TERM>Extramural Activities</TERM>
    <TERM>Extramural Research Facilities Construction Project</TERM>
    </PROJECT_TERMSX>
    <PROJECT_TITLE>The Center for Oral/Research</PROJECT_TITLE>
    <SUPPORT_YEAR>1</SUPPORT_YEAR>
    </row>
   </PROJECTS>
```

I can search for any of the single nodes using something like:

```
    SELECT   nref.value('(APPLICATION_ID)[1]', 'Int')    APPLICATION_ID,
    nref.value('(ACTIVITY)[1]', 'varchar(3)') ACTIVITY
    FROM [XML_2010] cross apply XMLData.nodes('//PROJECTS/row') as R(nref)
    WHERE  nref.value('(CORE_PROJECT_NUM)[1]', 'varchar(25)') LIKE '%CA187342%'
```

But how can I find the data associated with all XML files that have DOE, JOHN as a PI which is a sub node to PIS?  Such as the APPLICATION_ID and BUDGET_START etc?
Thanks for the help

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522491.aspx

Comment: Are all of your XMLs same in structure? Your code looks like you are using the *real XML* data type, but your example starts with `<?xml version="1.0"?>`? Is this stored as string (which column data type?) or do you read this from file? Are you always looking for the same information to filter or might you need any information from inside? On the first sight I'd suggest to write some of the values in indexed side columns. Maybe write the whole lot into a normal table?

Comment: All of the XML files are the same structure.  Data type is XML.  I parsed the XML data file that I get that holds around 100K records into separate files.  If there is a better way I'm open to suggestions.  Should I parse everything into normal tables?  What I was hoping for it to find the records associated to a PI and then parse them into tables.  I don't need all of the 100K records but I don't know which ones until I search

Answer (score 0):

XML is great for archives and data exchange, but is the wrong container to store actively used / filtered / searched data. Therefore I'd strongly suggest to transfer all your data in classical, indexed tables like this:

**Attention** I reduce your XML to some examples per level, the rest follows the same approach and is up to you. The declared table variable is to *mock-up* a test scenario:

```
DECLARE @YourTable TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,YourXml XML);
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES
('<PROJECTS xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <row>
    <APPLICATION_ID>7000518</APPLICATION_ID>
    <ACTIVITY>C06</ACTIVITY>
    <!-- more first level elements like above -->

    <!-- Here there are multiple PIs -->
    <PIS>
      <PI>
        <PI_NAME>JONES,MARY</PI_NAME>
        <PI_ID>9876543</PI_ID>
      </PI>
      <PI>
        <PI_NAME>DOE, JOHN</PI_NAME>
        <PI_ID>1234567</PI_ID>
      </PI>
    </PIS>

    <!-- Here there are multiple PROJECT_TERMS -->
    <PROJECT_TERMSX>
      <TERM>Extramural Activities</TERM>
      <TERM>Extramural Research Facilities Construction Project</TERM>
    </PROJECT_TERMSX>


    <!-- These are normal first level elements again -->
    <PROJECT_TITLE>The Center for Oral/Research</PROJECT_TITLE>
    <SUPPORT_YEAR>1</SUPPORT_YEAR>
  </row>
</PROJECTS>');
```

--This `SELECT` reads all *first-level-data* together with the partial XMLs into a temp table `#Projects`:

```
SELECT r.value('(APPLICATION_ID/text())[1]','bigint') AS APPLICATION_ID
      ,r.value('(ACTIVITY/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS ACTIVITY
      --more columns like above
      ,r.query('PIS') AS AllPis
      ,r.query('PROJECT_TERMSX') AS AllProjectTerms
      --more first level columns
INTO #Projects
FROM @YourTable AS t
OUTER APPLY t.YourXml.nodes('/PROJECTS/row') AS A(r);
```

--This `SELECT` reads from `#Projects` and stores all related *PI-data* in another temp table `#PIs`

```
SELECT APPLICATION_ID
      ,p.value('(PI_ID/text())[1]','bigint') AS PI_ID
      ,p.value('(PI_NAME/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS PI_NAME
INTO #PIs
FROM #Projects AS p
OUTER APPLY p.AllPis.nodes('PIS/PI') AS A(p);
```

--Same with `#Terms`

```
SELECT APPLICATION_ID
      ,t.value('(./text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS TERM
INTO #Terms
FROM #Projects AS p
OUTER APPLY p.AllProjectTerms.nodes('PROJECT_TERMSX/TERM') AS A(t);
```

--This is now the content of your temp tables

```
SELECT * FROM #Projects;
SELECT * FROM #PIs;
SELECT * FROM #Terms;

--Clean up
GO
DROP TABLE #Projects;
DROP TABLE #PIs;
DROP TABLE #Terms;
```

Before the `Clean up` you will enter some code, which writes your data out of these staging tables into real tables. The IDs to define the relation are stored together with the data. This should be easy. You will need `INSERT INTO` or `MERGE`, depending if you have to deal with already existing data.

### Hint

You might think about a `m:n`-relation between `projects and PIs` and `projects and terms`. For this you'd write a separate PI-table and a separate Term-table with a mapping table in between (holding the application_id and the second id, both as foreign keys)