# Moving database XML column data to new related tables

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, database, stored-procedures

Basically I have two tables, `Teachertbl` with primary key of `TeacherID`, and `TeacherBlobtbl` with `TeacherID` relating to `TeacherTbl`, as well as an XML column `TeacherBLOB`.

The `TeacherBLOB` XML data holds teacher data such as their class and students.

The schema for the tables look like the following:

**TeacherTbl:**

```
TeacherID int PRIMARY KEY    
-- Other columns
```

**TeacherBlobTbl:**

```
TeacherID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES TeacherTbl (TeacherID)
TeacherBlob xml
```

A sample of the XML in `TeacherBlob` looks like the following:

```
<Teacher>
. . .
    <TeacherClass>
        <FormRoom> Room A</FormRoom>
        <TotalStudents> 25 </TotalStudents>
        <Subject> Mathematics </Subject>
            <Student>
                <StudentName> James </StudentName>
                <StudentAge> 15 </StudentAge>
                <StudentAddress> </StudentAddress>
            </Student>
    </TeacherClass>
</Teacher>
```

Basically I want to get `TeacherClass` and `Student` and move them to their own tables. I want to grab `TeacherClass` and it's data to a new table with a foreign key relating to `TeacherTbl`.

In addition to this I want to grab each `Student` associated with `StudentClass` and move it into it's own table with a foreign key relating to `TeacherClass`.

Note: I do not want to move `Teacher` into its own table, I am only concerned about `TeacherClass` and `Student`.

It should look something like the following:

**TeacherClasstbl:**

```
TeacherClassID int PRIMARY KEY
FormRoom VARCHAR(50)
TotalStudents int
Subject VARCHAR(100)
TeacherID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES TeacherTbl(TeacherID)
```

**Studenttbl:**

```
StudentID int PRIMARY KEY
StudentName VARCHAR(50)
StudentAge int
StudentAddress VARCHAR(100)
TeacherClass int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES TeacherClassTbl(TeacherClassID)
```

It's also worth noting that not every XML `Teacher` will have an associated `TeacherClass` element and that the solution will need to cater for new data coming in to the `TeacherBlobTbl`.

Please let me know any tools/technologies I could use to achieve this.

I've thought about making a stored procedure that runs on a schedule, not sure if there is a better solution.

Thank you!

Comment: How do you handle the case where a student is in more than one class?  How do you want to assign teacher id and student id?

Comment: I could make it a many to many relationship with have a table between Student and Class. Teacher and Student will not be directly related, Student can be obtained through the TeacherClass, and TeacherClass can be obtained through Teacher.

Comment: I shortly [answered a related question here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41945435/5089204)

Comment: I would use SQL Server Integration Services for this. It has tasks to deal with xml data, as well pure c# code for more complex scenarios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest to read each level into staging tables table and to the actual transfer from there:

I use declared table variables to *mock-up* your test scenario

```
DECLARE @Teacher TABLE(TeacherID INT IDENTITY,Name VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @Teacher VALUES('Teacher 1'),('Teacher 2');
DECLARE @TeacherBLOB TABLE(TeacherBLOBID INT IDENTITY,TeacherID INT /*FK*/, TeacherBLOB XML);
INSERT INTO @TeacherBLOB VALUES
 (1,'<Teacher>
    <TeacherClass>
        <FormRoom> Room A</FormRoom>
        <TotalStudents> 25 </TotalStudents>
        <Subject> Mathematics </Subject>
            <Student>
                <StudentName> James </StudentName>
                <StudentAge> 15 </StudentAge>
                <StudentAddress> </StudentAddress>
            </Student>
    </TeacherClass>
</Teacher>')
,(1,'<Teacher>
    <TeacherClass>
        <FormRoom> Room B</FormRoom>
        <TotalStudents> 20 </TotalStudents>
        <Subject> Physics </Subject>
            <Student>
                <StudentName> Jane </StudentName>
                <StudentAge> 13 </StudentAge>
                <StudentAddress> Some address </StudentAddress>
            </Student>
            <Student>
                <StudentName> Tim </StudentName>
                <StudentAge> 14 </StudentAge>
                <StudentAddress> Some address </StudentAddress>
            </Student>
    </TeacherClass>
</Teacher>')
,(2,'<Teacher>
    <TeacherClass>
        <FormRoom> Room B</FormRoom>
        <TotalStudents> 20 </TotalStudents>
        <Subject> German </Subject>
            <Student>
                <StudentName> Hugo </StudentName>
                <StudentAge> 14 </StudentAge>
                <StudentAddress> Some address </StudentAddress>
            </Student>
            <Student>
                <StudentName> Max </StudentName>
                <StudentAge> 13 </StudentAge>
                <StudentAddress> Some address </StudentAddress>
            </Student>
    </TeacherClass>
</Teacher>');
```

--The first query reads the TeacherClass

```
SELECT t.Name
      ,tc.query('.') AS TeacherClassXML
      ,tc.value('FormRoom[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS FormRoom
      ,tc.value('TotalStudents[1]','int') AS TotalStudents
INTO #TeacherClass
FROM @Teacher AS t
INNER JOIN @TeacherBLOB AS tb ON t.TeacherID=tb.TeacherID
OUTER APPLY tb.TeacherBLOB.nodes('/Teacher/TeacherClass') AS A(tc);
```

--The second query reads the subjects

```
SELECT tc.*
      ,s.query('.') AS SubjectXML
      ,tc.TeacherClassXML.value('(TeacherClass/Subject)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS [Subject]
INTO #Subject
FROM #TeacherClass AS tc
OUTER APPLY tc.TeacherClassXML.nodes('TeacherClass/Subject') AS B(s)
```

--This query reads the students

```
SELECT tc.*
      ,tc.TeacherClassXML.value('(TeacherClass/Subject)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS [Subject]
      ,st.query('.') AS StudentXML
      ,st.value('StudentName[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS StudentName
      ,st.value('StudentAge[1]','int') AS StudentAge
      ,st.value('StudentAddress[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS StudentAddress
INTO #Student
FROM #TeacherClass AS tc
OUTER APPLY tc.TeacherClassXML.nodes('TeacherClass/Student') AS B(st)
```

--Check the content

```
SELECT * FROM #TeacherClass;
SELECT * FROM #Subject;
SELECT * FROM #Student;
```

--Clean-up for testing

```
GO
DROP TABLE #Student;
DROP TABLE #Subject;
DROP TABLE #TeacherClass;
```

Before the *Clean-Up* you have to place your code to fill your real tables.