# Extracting data from XML datatype in SQL

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql, stored-procedures, xmltable

I have a table called TeacherTbl which looks like:

```
TeacherTbl:

TeacherID INT PRIMARY KEY    
TeacherBlob XML
```

The TeacherBlob field looks like the following:

```
<Teacher>
. . .
    <TeacherClass>
        <FormRoom> Room A</FormRoom>
        <TotalStudents> 25 </TotalStudents>
        <Subject> Mathematics </Subject>
            <Student>
                <StudentName> James </StudentName>
                <StudentAge> 15 </StudentAge>
                <StudentAddress> </StudentAddress>
            </Student>
    </TeacherClass>
</Teacher>
```

I have written a stored procedure to navigate through this XML and extract the TeacherClass and Subject node values into separate relational tables, and are inserted into tables TeacherClass and Subject respectively.

Basically I want to select the ID's from the TeacherBlob XML that do not have existent data in the TeacherClass and Subject tables (ie. the INSERT statement in my stored procedure has failed). I only want to select the ID's when the parent node is a Teacher and has a TeacherClass child (TeacherClass may not exist for a Teacher).

Furthermore I am to attempt to reinsert this xml data into the TeacherClass and Subject nodes provided the data does not already exist in the tables (which is to be done in a seperate script). However this is not my primary struggle - I am struggling selecting the IDs which have Teacher and TeacherClass in the TeacherBlob given that I am not familiar with XML as a field type in T-SQL.

Any help with this would be great.

Comment: I can't help you with your specific problem but I would like to highlight that you are doing relational > XML > relational storage here. This would be so much easier if you just stored the data directly relationally (i.e. in a teacher table, a class table, a subject table, a student table). You may have reasons for what you're doing but you might want to reconsider.

Comment: Unfortunately this was the spec I was given - I had to implement my solution in the way that I did.

Comment: What XPath are you currently using and what issue do you have with it?

Comment: [I gave you an answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41992289/5089204) how to read this structure. If I understand your problem correctly, there is no clean way because there are no unique keys present. A student "James" might exist twice... And you should really never store the age as `INT`! What happens next year? Please provide a reduced but realistic *stand-alone* sample. You might use my code from the answer to your related question. Then show us the expected output. No chance to help you out at the moment...